# Failure with creating custom alias in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bash, haskell, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer and I am trying to create a custom alias so that I can run the ghc (Haskell compiler).
I tried editing the .bash_aliases file and added the commands:

```
alias ghci1 = 'GHC_HOME=$HOME/Development/bin/ghc'
alias ghci2 = 'PATH=$GHC_HOME/bin:${PATH}'
alias ghcis = 'ghci'
```

The whole point of doing this is because I installed ghc 7.8.3 and everytime I want to open the ghci I have to write down the first two commands, otherwise I get the error that ghc is not installed on my computer.

When I open a terminal after having edited the .bash_aliases file I get the messages:

```
bash: alias: ghci1: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: ghci2: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: ghcis: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: ghci: not found
bash: alias: ghci1: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
```

What am I doing wrong? I even tried the command:

. ~/.bashrc

just in case there is something wrong with the .bash_aliases file but I get the same error message.

Also when I type in the command `alias` I get as a result along with the other aliases this:

```
alias GHC_HOME='$HOME/Development/bin/ghc'
alias PATH='$GHC_HOME/bin:${PATH}'
```

So my aliases don't get the names that I assigned to them. Is there a way to somehow escape the '=' character or something like that for this to work?

P.S. The guide that I used to install ghc 7.8.3 is this:

```
https://gist.github.com/yantonov/10083524
```

So is there maybe a better way to install ghc 7.8.3, or am I assigning the aliases in a wrong way?

Thank you.

Comment: do what @ChrisDrost answer says. you shouldn't be trying to set environment variables via aliasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using the **export** built-in command in bash to set these up, and then GHCI will work correctly.

At the top or bottom of `~/.bashrc` you should write:

```
export GHC_HOME=$HOME/Development/bin/ghc
export PATH=$GHC_HOME/bin:${PATH}
```

Then once you have started a new bash instance you will have access to `ghci`. (If you need to do a live change, you can also `source ~/.bashrc` to reload that file into bash, which will bring the needed definitions.)

Comment: this is a better answer than mine. I didn't actually look at what he was trying to alias.

Comment: THANK YOU. I have been trying to figure it out for 1,5 hour :D

Answer (score 1):

remove the space before and after the '='

it should be

```
alias ghci1='GHC_HOME=$HOME/Development/bin/ghc'
```